# What is the most efficient way to check if two imageviews intersect?

Tags: android, imageview, intersection

I am currently working on an android app where I have one fixed imageview in the middle of the screen and other imageviews moving towards it. I would like to implement a method that will notify me as soon as one of the moving images touches the middle one. This is what I am using right now:

```
public void checkLoss() {
    if(spekList.size() > 0) {
        for(Spek spek : spekList) {
            final int[] position = new int[2];

            spek.getLocationInWindow(position);
            final Rect rect1 = new Rect(position[0], position[1], position[0] + spek.getWidth(),       position[1] + spek.getHeight());

            middle.getLocationInWindow(position);
            final Rect rect2 = new Rect(position[0], position[1],position[0] + middle.getWidth(), position[1] + middle.getHeight());

            if(Rect.intersects(rect1, rect2)) {
                if (health == 1) {
                    lost = true;
                    gameOver();
                    break;
                } else {
                    health--;
                    setMiddleImage(health);
                    removeSpek(spek);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works but I realized it's not that accurate. More often than not the moving images will reach all the way into the middle of the fixed one before I get the notification, whereas I would like it to happen as soon as the borders touch. Is there some sort of library that offers this? And if there is, how easy is it to implement it?

Thanks for your support :)

Comment: tried `getGlobalVisibleRect` and `getLocalVisibleRect` ?

Comment: how would i do that? I just read through the api info, don't really get it

Comment: `Rect r1 = new Rect(); Rect r2 = new Rect(); imgv1.getGlobalVisibleRect(r1); imgv2.getGlobalVisibleRect(r1);` then use `intersects` method

Comment: Doesn't work :/ I don't getGlobalVisibleRect() has any effect on either the rect object or the imageview since it only returns a boolean